# what are the advantages and disadvantages of embedding a script in the HTML of webpages?

Tags: html

I am trying to find out why people embed a script into the HTML of a webpage by using the advantages and disadvantages of doing so.

Comment: i have already looked at the question 'when should i use inline vs. external JavaScript' and yet i doesn't give me the answers i need.

Comment: Unfortunately your question is both too broad and primarily opinion-based, which are both reason for it to be off-topic for this site.